# Conformance Profile for ORU^R01 message with HAPI sample

Tags: hl7, hapi, hl7-v2

I am not able to validate an **ORU_R01** and **ADT_A04** (HL7 **v2.3.1**) messages with HAPI api (version 2.2) against the conformance profile generated from **MWB** (Message Workbench).

- First Problem is regarding the name assigned to segment group by MWB in conformance profile for ORU_R01 message, where **PATIENT_RESULT** is the segment group name generated by **MWB** (Message Workbench), and **PIDPD1NK1NTEPV1PV2ORCOBRNTEOBXNTECTI** is the way HAPI refers the same segment group in its api.
- If I replace **PATIENT_RESULT** with **PIDPD1NK1NTEPV1PV2ORCOBRNTEOBXNTECTI** in the profile, then profile becomes in valid for HAPI api parser.

**Below are the validation logs for the above mentioned problem:**

1. ValidationException - **PATIENT_RESULT** not found in message
2. ValidationException - The structure **PIDPD1NK1NTEPV1PV2ORCOBRNTEOBXNTECTI** appears in the message but not in the profile

**The second problem is in OBX segment for the datatype to be used in OBX.5 field.** 
Since my message contains multiple OBXs and also have multiple datatypes say **NM** and **ST** in OBX.2 field, 
Thus I cannot have a fixed datatype for OBX.5 in conformance profile, so I tried  "VARIES" provided by HAPI api for datatype placeholder in conformance profile at OBX.5 datatype declaration. But this also didn't work.

**Below are the validation logs for the above mentioned problem:**

1. ValidationException - HL7 datatype **NM** doesn't match profile datatype VARIES at OBX-5
2. ValidationException - HL7 datatype **ST** doesn't match profile datatype VARIES at OBX-5

---

**Below is the message:**

- MSH|^~\&|aa|bb|cc|3910|200903230934||ORU^R01^ORU_R01|75535037-123781|P^T|2.3.1
- EVN|A31|200903230934
- PID|1||29^^||Test300^Leticia^^^^^L||19770202|M||
- OBX||**NM**|abc||**121**||||||F||
- OBX||**ST**|def||**jaiswal**||||||F||

---

**Below is the Profile Snippet :**

```
    <SegGroup Name="**PATIENT_RESULT**" LongName="PATIENT_RESULT" Usage="R" Min="1" Max="*">
        <SegGroup Name="**PATIENT**" LongName="PATIENT" Usage="O" Min="0" Max="1">
            <Segment Name="**PID**" LongName="patient identification segment" Usage="R" Min="1" Max="1">
                <Field Name="Set ID - PID" Usage="O" Min="0" Max="1" Datatype="SI" Length="4" ItemNo="00104">
```

---

```
    <Segment Name="OBX" LongName="observation/result segment" Usage="O" Min="0" Max="*">

        <Field Name="Set ID - OBX" Usage="O" Min="0" Max="1" Datatype="SI" Length="4" ItemNo="00569">
            <Reference>OBX-1</Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Value Type" Usage="R" Min="1" Max="1" Datatype="ID" Length="3" Table="0125" ItemNo="00570">
            <Reference>OBX-2</Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Observation Identifier" Usage="R" Min="1" Max="1" Datatype="CE" Length="1000" ItemNo="00571">
            <Reference>OBX-3</Reference>
            <Component Name="identifier" Usage="O" Datatype="ST" Length="1000">
                <Reference>OBX-3-1</Reference>
            </Component>
            <Component Name="text" Usage="O" Datatype="ST" Length="1000">
                <Reference>OBX-3-2</Reference>
            </Component>
            <Component Name="name of coding system" Usage="O" Datatype="ST" Length="3">
                <Reference>OBX-3-3</Reference>
            </Component>
            <Component Name="alternate identifier" Usage="O" Datatype="ST" Length="3">
                <Reference>OBX-3-4</Reference>
            </Component>
            <Component Name="alternate text" Usage="O" Datatype="ST" Length="3">
                <Reference>OBX-3-5</Reference>
            </Component>
            <Component Name="name of alternate coding system" Usage="O" Datatype="ST" Length="3">
                <Reference>OBX-3-6</Reference>
            </Component>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Observation Sub-ID" Usage="O" Min="1" Max="1" Datatype="ST" Length="20" ItemNo="00572">
            <Reference>OBX-4</Reference>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Observation Value" Usage="O" Min="0" Max="1" Datatype="**VARIES**" Length="65536" ItemNo="00573">
            <Reference>OBX-5</Reference>
        </Field>
```

Regards,
Amar Jaiswal

Comment: What question are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, if the intent of the question is not clear.

The hapi api is giving me validation errors for the Conformance profile, that I have generated from MWB.

The way MWB assigns names for segment group in conformance profile, say "PATIENT_RESULT", which hapi complains about as : 
           ValidationException - The structure PIDPD1NK1NTEPV1PV2ORCOBRNTEOBXNTECTI appears in the message but not in the profile.

And that is because when hapi parses the ORU message, it has segment group under PIDPD1NK1NTEPV1PV2ORCOBRNTEOBXNTECTI after the MSH segment.

Comment: And the second question is : in OBX.5 (5th field of OBX segment) the value should be in accordance with the datatype defined in OBX.2 field of the same segment.

But I have multiple segments of OBX with different type of datatypes each for OBX.2 field, and OBX.5 datatype defined as "VARIES", even then the validation fails, with exception as below : 

        HL7 datatype NM doesn't match profile datatype VARIES at OBX-5

Comment: Perhaps you could post your message so we know what you're referring to.

Comment: 1. Problem is with multiple OBX in single message with different datatypes in OBX.2, where as OBX.5 in conformance profile also expects to define datatype, so it demands to switch between datatypes dynamically... Which is not possible through profile, so I used "VARIES" as placeholder for datatype provided by HAPI api v2.2.

Comment: Hi Gabe, I have restructured the question also have put the message being used and also snippet for the conformance profile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ST` as the data type for OBX.5 because I don't think there's any way to tell MWB that it needs to look in OBX.2 for the actual data type.

Comment: Hi Gabe, 
Actually that lookup and validation is done by HAPI api, which validates the message based upon the conformance Profile. Thats why HAPI has introduced the placeholder datatype as "VARIES".

But there seems to be a bug in HAPI, which does not support what it has to... BUt not sure...

Comment: @AmarJaiswal dare to step through the `HAPI` source code in the debugger and if you do pinpoint the wrong place, post a patch. That's in my eyes the best nowadays answer to your question, based on the wealth of know how you've already accumulated. Also, there may be some important info left in the `HAPI` source code comments (at least the time data type implementation was full of them)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for the problem with segment group names. (i.e the first problem I had posted earlier)

Change need to be made in regular expression '([A-Z]|)+' of message_profile.xml file at ca\uhn\hl7v2\conf\parser in hapi-base jar.

i.e. replace regular expression '([A-Z]|)+' of segment group name to '([A-Z0-9]|)+' in the message_profile.xml and rebuild the jar for hapi-base.

Now the ProfileException will not be thrown when using PIDPD1NK1NTEPV1PV2ORCOBRNTEOBXNTECTI as segment group name.